# How do I count the number of times a number satisfies a range (bigger than x, smaller than y) in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I have this spreadsheet in LibreOffice. I need to know how show the number of times a number, in Columns D and E, satisfies a certain range. For example, how many times a number is bigger than 3 and smaller than 6. If the column had {1,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,10}, it should return 6, the number of times which the condition is satisfied. How do I do that, using expressions or that "console" of LibreOffice?

Thanks for the answers.
[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

For a single logical condition, you can use the `COUNTIF()` function.

For multiple logical conditions, one solution suggested in the OpenOffice wiki [Conditional counting and summation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation) is to use the `SUMPRODUCT()` function:

[image]